# Apply configurable product images to ours associated simple products Magento 1.9.x

Tags: product-images, products, associated-products

I need to apply configurable product images to our simple product associated because I need to use simple products in another store where it will only show simple products and not show configurable products.

I use configurable products just to generate simple products but I don't know which setting inside Magento itself will allow applying these images to our simple products.

So, when I put the simple generated products to appear in the store, they appear without images because only the configurable product receives these images.

Is there a setup or module that applies images to configurable products and associated simple products?

```
PHP URL Code
https://santosmadeiras.com.br/to.php
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a script for the same. You can achieve this by executing the script on your website.

> For Magento 2

```
<?php 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

$configProductIds = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; //configurable product ids to update images

foreach ($configProductIds as $product_id) {
    $configProduct = $productCollection->load($product_id);

    $image = $configProduct->getImage();
    $thumbnail = $configProduct->getThumbnail();
    $smallImage = $configProduct->getSmallImage();

    $_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);

    foreach ($_children as $child){
        $childProduct = $productCollection->load($child->getId());
        $childProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($image, ['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'], false, false);
        $childProduct->save();
    }
}
```

> For Magento 1

```
<?php

define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());

include_once "app/Mage.php";

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

Mage::init();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

try {

    $configProductIds = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; //configurable product ids to update images

    foreach ($configProductIds as $product_id) {
    $configProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

    $image = $configProduct->getImage();
    $thumbnail = $configProduct->getThumbnail();
    $smallImage = $configProduct->getSmallImage();

    $childIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($configProduct->getId());

    foreach ($childIds as $childId){
        $childProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(childId);
        $childProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($image, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
        $childProduct->save();
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: I need to convert this from Magento 1.9.x ... Can you help me?

Comment: Updated my answer with Magento 1 script.

Comment: Script for Magento 1.9.x.x work like a charm but the url image don't save on simple associated products. Image and code url on updated question.

Comment: Issue is with the product attribute name, updated my answer, please check.

Comment: You have a bit error on the first line after second foreach (childId) ... even fixed this error, image don't saved on simple associated product on database.

Comment: OK, please give a try with my updated answer.

Comment: Fixed !! For all others that search for this, the absolute $image path its necessary on magento 1.9.x.x script to write path on database. Thanks Sumit.